# MQTT communication using and okd cluster

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, mosquitto, okd

I'm discorvering okd 3.11 and I must deploy an eclipse-mosquitto image. When I do it, I'm able to perform a mosquitto_sub and a mosquitto_pub using directly the pod IP address but I don't find the way to accept connexions arriving from other points of the networks.

```
apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
  creationTimestamp: '2021-11-05T16:01:43Z'
  generation: 3
  labels:
    app: eclipse-mosquitto2
  name: eclipse-mosquitto2
  namespace: mytestproject
  resourceVersion: '104434'
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/apps.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/mytestproject/deploymentconfigs/eclipse-mosquitto2
  uid: abd24410-3e51-11ec-af81-000c29fdfa6a
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: eclipse-mosquitto2
    deploymentconfig: eclipse-mosquitto2
  strategy:
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
    resources: {}
    rollingParams:
      intervalSeconds: 1
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      timeoutSeconds: 600
      updatePeriodSeconds: 1
    type: Rolling
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: eclipse-mosquitto2
        deploymentconfig: eclipse-mosquitto2
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: >-
            eclipse-mosquitto@sha256:27f2a3ca48ba6c4ae9b7942a0c8e7f0badd82373e3b88c3801d9fae59ac483f8
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: eclipse-mosquitto2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1883
              protocol: TCP
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /mosquitto/data
              name: eclipse-mosquitto2-1
            - mountPath: /mosquitto/log
              name: eclipse-mosquitto2-2
            - mountPath: /mosquitto/config
              name: volume-ggqdt
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
        - emptyDir: {}
          name: eclipse-mosquitto2-1
        - emptyDir: {}
          name: eclipse-mosquitto2-2
        - configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            items:
              - key: mosquitto.conf
                path: mosquitto.conf
            name: mosquitto-config
          name: volume-ggqdt
  test: false
  triggers:
    - type: ConfigChange
    - imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
          - eclipse-mosquitto2
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: 'eclipse-mosquitto2:latest'
          namespace: mytestproject
        lastTriggeredImage: >-
          eclipse-mosquitto@sha256:27f2a3ca48ba6c4ae9b7942a0c8e7f0badd82373e3b88c3801d9fae59ac483f8
      type: ImageChange
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: '2021-11-05T16:01:54Z'
      lastUpdateTime: '2021-11-05T16:01:54Z'
      message: Deployment config has minimum availability.
      status: 'True'
      type: Available
    - lastTransitionTime: '2021-11-05T16:05:28Z'
      lastUpdateTime: '2021-11-05T16:05:31Z'
      message: replication controller "eclipse-mosquitto2-2" successfully rolled out
      reason: NewReplicationControllerAvailable
      status: 'True'
      type: Progressing
  details:
    causes:
      - type: ConfigChange
    message: config change
  latestVersion: 2
  observedGeneration: 3
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 0
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Could someone explain me what is wrong with my deployment?

Thanks in advance,

Remi

Comment: You can't use hostname based ingress (at least without TLS) because MQTT is not HTTP so there is no HOST header to know which container to proxy for.

Comment: I also tried to use the externalIp feature but okd returns me the error "spec.externalIPs : Forbidden : externalIPs have been disabled".
I don't find in the documentation how to enable the feature

Comment: ExternalIP support normally requires a LoadBalancer component, how that is provided will depend on your environment.